# Digital filtering on a microcontroller using integer math

Tags: algorithms, signal-processing, recursive-algorithms, integers

First of all, please be patient with this post, I don't know how to explain my problem in a shorter way. Thank you in advance! :)

I have a question regarding recursive difference equations implemented using integer variables.

Let us suppose that I want to filter an input signal $u(t)$ with a cut-off frequency $f_f=\frac{1}{2\pi T_f}$. In the continuous time domain, the filter transfer function is:

$$G_\mathcal{L}(s)=\frac{1}{1+sT_f}.$$

The equivalent transfer function in the $\mathcal{Z}$-domain that has the same response to a step function $u(t)=\mu(t)$ (in other words, $G_\mathcal{L}(s)$ is discretized using the ZOH discretization method) is defined as follows:

$$G_\mathcal{Z} = \frac{(1-a)z^{-1}}{1-az^{-1}}, \quad a=e^{-\frac{T_s}{T_f}}, \quad 0<a<1,$$

where $T_s$ is the system sample time. The recursive difference equation is:

$$y_n = u_{n-1} + \frac{K}{M} \bigl( y_{n-1} - u_{n-1} \bigr), \quad a=\frac{K}{M}, \quad n,K,M\in\mathbb{Z}, $$

where $n$ is the time index, $y_n \equiv y(n)$ and $u_n \equiv u(n)$. Note that I usually choose $M$ to be of the form $M=2^b$, where $b \in \mathbb{N}$, so that I don't need to use a divide instruction which requires a lot of instruction cycles on a microcontroller, i.e., I can use a bit shift instruction instead, as follows:

```
y = u + ( K * ( y - u ) ) >> b );
```

Please note that in this "integer division" operation using the bit shift (`>>b`), the result is always rounded towards the first lower number, i.e., `4/3=1` and `(-4)/3=-2`.

**Example 1.** Let us calculate an evolution of $y$ for input $u(n)=10000\mu(n)$, initial condition $y(0)=0$, and filter parameters $K=311$ and $M=512$.

This difference equation would evolve on a microcontroller as follows:

```
k     y(k)    u(k)    y(k+1)
0     0       10000   3925
1     3925    10000   6309
2     6309    10000   7758
...   ...     ...     ...
18    9997    10000   9998
19    9998    10000   9998
20    9998    10000   9998
```

As you can see, the digital filter output never reaches the input value, i.e. the error is $e_\infty = 2$. How can I formalize this error, i.e., is it possible to calculate the $e_\infty$ from $K$ and $M$ only? I've run several simulations of the system, it seems that the error $e_\infty$ doesn't depend on the input signal. Please find attached a diagram of $e_\infty$ vs. $K$ for a fixed $M=2^9$.

[image: steady-state error vs. K]

The interesting thing here is if we change the initial condition to be greater than $u$, for example, $y(0)=20000$, then the digital filter manages to reach the final value for all $0<K<M$.

I managed to find a solution to this problem, as follows:

```
z = K * ( y - u )
if (z < 0) {
    Z = Z + c;
}
y = u + (Z >> b);
```

where `c=(2^b)-1`. In other words, I round toward `0` for negative numbers.

However, I'm not comfortable using this solution, as I don't fully understand what happens here. Is there any smarter solution than the one with rounding toward `0`? Can you suggest some tutorials (articles) on how to implement algorithms using integer math only. I don't want to reinvent hot water here :)

If you managed to reach until the end of this post, once again, I'm sorry for the large post! :)

Comment: What exactly are you not comfortable with? Is it only about preferring to round negative values towards the nearest smaller integer (instead of towards $0$), as you do with positive values? Or is there something else that you're not pleased with?

Comment: Since I don't fully understand the mechanism here, I don't know if this is going to work for all examples. Can this error $e_\infty$ be formalized via $K$ and $M$ parameters? Is this happening only because of the rounding?

Comment: I think this question should be posted on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I forgot to add $z^{-1}$ in the nominator of the transfer function $G_\mathcal{Z}$, therefore it should be $u_{n-1}$. Thank you for your suggestion to post this in the signal processing forum.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Filter Design with Low Complexity Coefficients](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/filt_coef_trunc.html) (2008) and the references therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find an answer to my question. The steady-state error $e_\infty$ can be estimated as:

$$e_\infty = \left\lfloor \frac{M-1}{M-K} \right\rfloor, \quad M,K\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

**Here is a proof.**

Let us recall the difference equation:

$$y_n = u_{n-1} + \frac{K}{M}\left( y_{n-1}-u_{n-1} \right) , \quad u,y,n\in\mathbb{Z},$$

where $M=2^b$, $b\in\mathbb{N}$, and $-M<K<M$ for a system to be stable.

If we write $e_n = y_n - u_n$, then this equation can be written as:

$$e_n = \frac{K}{M}e_{n-1}, \quad e\in\mathbb{Z},$$

since $u_{k-1} = u_k$. Assuming that the system is stable, this equation can be rewritten for a steady state as follows:

$$e_\infty = \left\lfloor \frac{K}{M}e_\infty \right\rfloor, \quad e_\infty\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

Now let us assume that for the decimal number on the RHS of the previous equation we use a floor function, i.e., $\lfloor1.3\rfloor=1$ and $\lfloor-1.3\rfloor=-2$.

If we assume for example that $e_\infty=-2$, then the RHS of the previous equation (assuming that we use a floor function) needs to be:

$$\frac{K}{M} (-2) < (-1) .$$

Let us solve this inequality:

$$\frac{K}{M} \geq \frac{1}{2} \rightarrow K \geq M \cdot \frac{1}{2}$$

For $M=512$ and $e_\infty=-2$, the parameter $K$ is at least $K=256$. Simulations of the system have shown that for $K=256$ the steady-state error is $e_\infty=-1$, and here we predicted it to be $e_\infty=-2$. I'm still not sure what is wrong in this reasoning, but this can be fixed by replacing $\geq$ with $>$ in the previous ineqaulity. The previous equation can be generalized as follows:

$$K > M \cdot \frac{e_\infty + 1}{e_\infty} .$$

Now let us see how this inequality works for $M=512$ and different $e_\infty$:

```
if e = -1 then K > 0
if e = -2 then K > 256
if e = -3 then K > 341.33
if e = -4 then K > 384
if e = -5 then K > 409.6
```

This table has been confirmed by simulating the system for different $K$.

Now let us see how this table looks like for positive errors:

```
if e = +1 then K > 1024    (not a feasible solution)
if e = +2 then K > 768     (not a feasible solution)
if e = +3 then K > 682.66  (not a feasible solution)
```

In other words, for any $K < M$, there is no positive steady-state error. This has been also confirmed by simulations. Following the same explanation, if we use a ceil function instead of a floor function, we get the same problem for the positive steady-state errors.

Conclusion: a floor function should be used for positive decimal numbers, and a ceil function should be used for negative decimal numbers. In that case there will be no error in the steady-state condition.

```
Z = K * ( y - u );
if ( Z < 0 ) {
    Z = Z + ( (1<<b) - 1 );
}
y = u + ( Z >> b );
```

I know that this is not a strict mathematical proof, but it is confirmed by simulations.